# Users getting logged out after a short amount of time

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am having some issue with session. The users gets logged out after a short amount of time. I have read some tutorials and a few questions/answers here on SO, but I can't seems to find the issue.

This is on the top of `login.php`:

```
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["isloggedin"]) && $_SESSION["isloggedin"] === true){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

This is the code I run when the user has successfully logged in:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600); // Make session last for 1 hour before user has to login again
session_set_cookie_params(3600); // Make session last for 1 hour before user has to login again
$_SESSION["isloggedin"] = true;
$_SESSION["team"] = $currentTeam;
```

This is the code I have in top of all pages on my website:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['isloggedin'])) { // If not logged in, redirect to login page
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

$team = $_SESSION["team"];
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How is the problem manifesting? Are the users able to navigate for a while after being logged in? Are there polling requests?